# Creating a function in R that takes input as dataframe , orders it grouped columns and generates a sequence. New column isnt coming in DF1

Tags: r

```
#Function that takes df1,group_vars as input and return df1 with seq columns as output
get_seq <- function(df1,group_vars) {
      
      df1<-df1[ with( df1, do.call(order, mget(group_vars)) ), ]
      
        df1<-df1 %>%
        group_by(.dots=group_vars) %>%
        mutate(seq=row_number())
      
      return(df1)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this function :

```
library(dplyr)

get_seq <- function(df1, group_vars) {
  df1 %>%
    arrange(across(all_of(group_vars))) %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(group_vars))) %>%
    mutate(seq=row_number())
}
```

You can call this function as :

```
df2 <- get_seq(df1, 'col1')
df2 <- get_seq(df1, c('col1', 'col2'))
```

Comment: I tried using this method, it throws an error says "Error in across(all_of(group_vars)) : could not find function "across""

Comment: `across` has been introduced in `dplyr` 1.0.0 update your package to newest version with  `install.packages('dplyr')`

Answer (score 1):

It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. If you want to pass a variable number of column names to a function, sort the data frame according to these columns, then `group_by` the columns, then add a row number within each subgroup, you would do:

```r
get_seq <- function(df1, ...) 
{
  group_vars <- enquos(...)
  
  df1 %>%
    arrange(!!!group_vars) %>%
    group_by(!!!group_vars) %>%
    mutate(seq = row_number())
}
```

So if we had a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(1:3, each = 4), 
                 b = rep(LETTERS[4:1], each = 3),
                 c = rnorm(12))
```

We could do:

```
get_seq(df, a, b)

#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   a, b [6]
#>        a b           c   seq
#>    <int> <fct>   <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1 C      0.779      1
#>  2     1 D      0.318      1
#>  3     1 D     -0.0710     2
#>  4     1 D      0.183      3
#>  5     2 B     -0.351      1
#>  6     2 B      0.401      2
#>  7     2 C     -1.26       1
#>  8     2 C      1.99       2
#>  9     3 A     -0.0723     1
#> 10     3 A     -0.602      2
#> 11     3 A      2.05       3
#> 12     3 B      2.13       1
```